# how to run --publish-local-settings when doing a right click deploy?

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, azure-functions

When performing a **right click --> deploy** on a function app, how do we provide the `--publish-local-settings` switch?

[image]

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#local-settings-file) states:

> By default, these settings are not migrated automatically when the
>   project is published to Azure. Use the --publish-local-settings switch
>   when you publish to make sure these settings are added to the function
>   app in Azure.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer?  You can't.  That flag is for the func.exe command line tool, not visual studio right-click publish.

Long answer: From the screenshot, it looks like you are using Visual Studio, yes? By default, Visual Studio doesn't publish your `local.settings.json` file to Azure.  The expectation there is that your local development settings *probably* aren't the same settings you want published.  They are nudging you into the pit of success.

To publish settings from inside Visual Studio, follow the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs#function-app-settings) ...

> The easiest way to upload the required settings to your function app
> in Azure is to select the **Manage Azure App Service settings** link
> that appears after you successfully publish your project.
>
> [image]
>
> Selecting this link displays the **Application settings** dialog for
> the function app, where you can add new application settings or modify
> existing ones.
>
> [image]

If you are **truly** looking to use the `--publish-local-settings` flag you are referencing, then that can be achieved using the azure functions core tools command line tool, func.exe

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows%2Ccsharp%2Cbash#publish).

Example command: `func azure functionapp publish Function_App_Name --publish-local-settings`